# How do I separate three different phone numbers concatenated in one cell into three new rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, macros, worksheet-function

I am doing work for a client and need to know how to separate these phone numbers.

I have

```
0121 396 0501 / 0121 123 434* / 0797 978 8265
```

in one cell and I want to end up with the same row duplicated 3 times, each time with a different phone number from this cell.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. We all volunteer our time to answer questions here. Asking for an answer ASAP is not constructive to getting a response.

Comment: sorry just the client has asked me to do it now at 10pm and needs this in tomorrow 8am and its a few hundred thousand cells all like this need seperating out

Comment: Do you know about the 'Text to Columns' feature on the Data tab?

Comment: @brad patton He probably doesn't know, that's why is in a state of panic and forgot his manners. The question is definitely not from a "superuser", it's basic Excel stuff. Still, I hope my answer will help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Text to Columns` feature on the `Data` tab.

Select that and choose `Delimited` and then click `Next`.

On the next screen choose `Other` and enter the `/` character. Click `Finish`

[image]

Comment: a) your original post does not include that you may want to go back and edit if 100% needed. b) you could split the data then use Find/Replace or other tools to clean it further.

Comment: brad do you have a skype which i could contact you on and give you all the details so you could help me 100%?

Comment: Sorry no. I do this to volunteer answers for the general public not consult (I get enough of that in my real job :) ).

Comment: Haha i will link a picture and annotate what i mean

Comment: a lot he has give me a sample of like 5 which you can see in the screen shot but when i go into the office tomorrow he will have hundreds of thousands for me to do, could i make a macro to do this for me?

Comment: Yeah I think for that many you would be best with a VB macro. You could maybe get by with a combination of Excel tools and VB. The text to columns will separate the data. Use Find and Replace in the cols to clear out the NA. Use VB to expand rows and copy move data. I have to take off now. Best of luck. (And if that is real person data you should delete the image and comment).

Answer (score 0):

Use the convert command on the data tab, choose delimited values, then next and chose custom sign & enter a slash / in the little box down, then next, then chose the text option, next. You should end up with three separate columns. Or if the phone numbers are always the same length you can use a formula. Put your data in column A and adapt the following playing with the second number between parenthsesis to get the desired number of digits:

```
Column B: right(a1;15)
Colum C:left((right(a1,32)),15)
Col. D:Left(a1, 15)
```

Comment: Dont understand what you mean by this?

Comment: @ConnorStandish: I think Jo meant enter a forward slash character, `/`, as the delimiter character in conjuction with the data tab convert command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND` to get the positions of the separators:

```
' first one
=FIND(" / ",A1)
' 14

' second one
=FIND(" / ",A1,FIND(" / ",A1)+1)
' 30
```

With this you can split up your text usign `LEFT`, `MID` and `RIGHT`:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" / ",A1)-1)
' 0121 396 0501
=MID(A1,FIND(" / ",A1)+3,FIND(" / ",A1,FIND(" / ",A1)+1)-FIND(" / ",A1)-3)
' 0121 123 434*
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" / ",A1,FIND(" / ",A1)+1)-2)
' 0797 978 8265
```

Note the offsets used to take into account of the size of the separator (3 characters).